# DB2 truncated output

Tags: sql, db2, truncate

when i make select (command prompt WinXP) like:

```
db2 select message_data from messages where message_id = 20043
```

i get output +

```
'Output is truncated' message.
message_data is LONG VARCHAR > 30000 characters
```

If i do like:

```
db2 select message_data from messages where message_id = 20043 > c:\otpt.xml
```

I get the same result. Is there any way to all data, not truncated?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a db2 export in order to retrieve the data.

db2 export to output.txt of del select message_data from messages where message_id = 20043

This will create a file calle output.txt that will have the value of column "message_data" between quotes.

Comment: I have old version of db2 and it doesn't support DEL, only IXF, which is not good for me.

Comment: you could also try the WSF type, that can be imported in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Also, you can change your db2 version, for the db2 v9r7 express-c which is free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

OK, that's limitation of CommandLineProcessor(CLP). Up to 8000 symbols (db29320w - bug/feature).
Other interface needed to run the query. For example MicrosotQuery in Office.